# Sidebar Functionality

Tags: google-apps-script

I have continued to develop a sidebar capability within my google sheet.
I have am looking for some assistance in creating a flow within the sidebar and using links or buttons to create some output messages.

Problem 1) - I have created a sidebar with forward and back arrows which I want to link other html files to when they are clicked within the sidebar, therefore creating a flow or dialog that can be moved back or forth in the same sequence. i.e.. I click next and the function openTheSidebar2() runs

I have have a search dropdown feature which in the code below gives Primary risk categories.

Problem 2) - I would like these to have the ability to provide a simple paragraph (explanation of each category) when they are selected. Would I need to create a different html file for each category? I'm hoping I can add the each message for each category in the same html file.
Is hyperlinks the wrong way to go about this altogether?

Any help is much appreciated

code.gs

```js
function onOpen() {
  menu();
}


function menu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Risk Menu')
  .addItem('Generate Risk Waiver', 'createNewCase')
  .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Risk Help')
             .addItem('Risk Guidance', 'openTheSidebar')
             .addItem('Risk Title', 'openTheSidebar2'))

  .addToUi();
}


function openTheSidebar() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example3').evaluate()
  .setTitle('Risk Rating');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function openTheSidebar2() {
  var userInterface2=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example4').evaluate()
    .setTitle('Primary Risk Category');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface2);
}

function openTheSidebar3() {
  var userInterface3=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example').evaluate()  
  .setTitle('Cause');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface3);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getRowColumn() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var rObj={row:rg.getColumn() ,column:rg.getRow()};
  return rObj;
}

function getCellA1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var rObj={A1:rg.getA1Notation()};
  return rObj;
}

function onCheckOpenSideBar(e) {


  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Option 1')return;
  if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==24) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheSidebar();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  } 
   if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Option 1')return;
   if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==8) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheSidebar2();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
   }

   if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Option 1')return;
   if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheSidebar3();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
   }}

function createOnEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onCheckOpenSideBar').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();

}
```

example4.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;

}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Categories</button>
  <a href="#" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" class="next round">&#8250</a>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
<a href="#IT Security & Vulnerability">IT Security & Vulnerability</a>
<a href="#Information Security - Data Only">Information Security - Data Only</a>
<a href="#Technical Debt or Decommission">Technical Debt or Decommission</a>
<a href="#Availability (SLA)">Availability (SLA)</a>
<a href="#Service Continuity & Resilience">Service Continuity & Resilience</a>
<a href="#Capacity & Performance">Capacity & Performance</a>
<a href="#Licencing & Asset Management, Contracts, Maintenance,">Licencing & Asset Management, Contracts, Maintenance,</a>
<a href="#Legal & Regulatory Compliance">Legal & Regulatory Compliance</a>
<a href="#Supplier & Vendor Management">Supplier & Vendor Management</a>
<a href="#Shadow IT">Shadow IT</a>
<a href="#Resource">Resource</a>
<a href="#Knowledge / Skills / Tooling)">Knowledge / Skills / Tooling)</a>
<a href="#Procedure & Process">Procedure & Process</a>
<a href="#Service Ownership">Service Ownership</a>
<a href="#Project">Project</a>
<a href="#Environmental (includes facilities)">Environmental (includes facilities)</a>
<a href="#Architecture and Strategic">Architecture and Strategic</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, but if I've got it wrong, just let me know.  Your question is somewhat broad and there are many solutions to what you want to do.  Here are a couple of ways I might start to approach it.

## Method 1: Serve it all at once; show and hide as needed

[As shown here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices), use a helper function `include` to break up your HTML files for development and then pull them all together when you run the app.

```js
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Content snippet in its own .html file, and give the outermost HTML element a distinct id.

```html
<section id="IT_Security_And_Vulnerability" class="hidden">
  <h1>IT Security & Vulnerability</h1>
  <p> ...
  </p>
</section>
```

Print all those html files into your main html file you return to the user.
Main html file snippets:

```html
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<?= include("#IT_Security_And_Vulnerability") ?>
<?= include("#Information_Security_Data_Only") ?>
<!-- etc -->

<script>
const body = document.querySelector("body"); // this just grabs the sidebar body
body.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
function handleClick(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.tagname != "A") { // this listener only for clicking links
    return;
  }
  clickEvent.target.preventDefault(); // you may or may not want/need this to prevent browser from trying to actually navigate with your <a> tag
  const id = clickEvent.target.getAttribute("href");
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
  for (let i = 0, l = sections.length; i < l; ++i) { // hide everyone
    sections[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
  document.querySelector(id).classList.remove("hidden"); // show the selected one
}
</script>
```

## Method 2: Use google.script.run to fetch content as needed

Still using the `include` function on the server, this serves up the content on demand.

```html
...
<section class="contentContainer">
<!-- populated by js -->
</section>
...
<script>
const body = document.querySelector("body"); // this just grabs the sidebar body
body.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function refresh(html) {
  const contentContainer = document.querySelector(".contentContainer");
  contentContainer.innerHTML = html;
}

function handleClick(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.tagname != "A") {
    return;
  }
  clickEvent.target.preventDefault(); // you may or may not want/need this.
  const reference = clickEvent.target.getAttribute("href");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refresh).include(reference);
}
</script>
```